# Стоит ли делать push в редюсере reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default function(state = [], action)
{
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case "ADD_COMMENT":

            state.push(action.payload)
            return state;
    
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

не будет ли считаться это плохим тоном?

Comment: Вы мутируете стейт. Лучше сделать его иммутабельным и возвращать новый объект (в вашем случае массив)

Comment: да знаю, но как это сделать. я не знаю как это задать в гугле. Если я напишу ...state, action.payload, тогда не будет массива объектов, а мне как раз нужен он

Comment: Разве вариант с `return [...state, action.payload]` не подойдёт? Ещё можно использовать concat

Comment: подойдет, спасибо:)*